# Virtual reality via neural stimulation

Tags: hard-science, brain, virtual-reality

I just learned that scientists are able to stimulate certain regions of a person's brain to make them feel certain emotions or move parts of their body.

I was wondering if it would be possible to program a headset to stimulate your brain such that it feels as if you are in virtual reality, while receiving signals from your brain used to move your 'avatar' around in the virtual reality, and keeping your actual physical body in a state of sleep. Is this feasible? Let's assume that technology at this time isn't much more advanced than technology today, and that we have limitless resources.

Thanks!

Comment: This seems to be a real world science question without worldbuilding context.  If you can [edit] the question to fit this Stack Exchange site's [FAQ] you're more likely to get a useful answer.  Also, please ask *one* question (ask the second in another separate question).

Comment: Ok - is there some science stack exchange I can post this on?

Comment: Probably not one where this kind of "can science fiction become science fact" question can stay open.  I'd recommend trying to [edit] to make it a Worldbuilding question built around the same idea (and then ask another about the dead brain).

Comment: If I knew how to do it, I'd be running to the patent office, not publishing it where it becomes public domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TLDR

Yes, this is theoretically possible *in the real world as we understand it.* Although nothing explicitly prevents it, there are still ***a lot*** of unknowns!

## The Scheme, Summarized

We do know that the [human nervous system](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nervous_system) receives stimulation via chemical receptors and sends signals via electrical pulses.

The naive approach to this would be to stimulate these nerves (chemically or otherwise) and simulate sensations. That's all well and good: we have been electrocuting muscles and messing with chemical receptors for various purposes for a long time now!

Complications arise when you get into the details. Where do you paralyze the body, how do you know you have the right nerve, and how do you know you're stimulating the correct nerve (and with the correct transmitter or signal)? That's a lot of research before you even simulate basic things!

## The Issues and Dangers

There are some severe dangers to this in addition to simple resource issues. It's a big undertaking, and my guess is that it wouldn't be so simple as [jacking in into the matrix](https://matrix.fandom.com/wiki/Jacking_in). We have some big questions to answer, like...

- What happens to someone who is continually exposed to the paralyzing agent?
- Can we interface with nerves without the body rejecting or attempting to heal over the interface? (Or altering brain structure too much?)
- Can we successfully stimulate *every* nerve?
- Can we avoid over/under stimulation? How much of each neurotransmitter is correct for each nerve? (And does the body desensitize to this? If it's variable, how do we know what's the "just right" amount?)
- Does the brain or body adjust to the abilities of the virtual self, only to over/under estimate it's actual physical abilities? In other words, if your avatar differs physically enough from your actual body, can you still use your body when you come back to it? (Center of mass, strength, coordination, etc.)